# How to create library for the plugin in cakephp 3.X

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

How to create library for the plugin in cakephp3.x and also what is folder structure for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more precise with your question and review the [CakePHP Cookbook Plugins Section](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins).

You can automatically create a plugin using the Bake Shell:

```
bin/cake bake plugin PluginName
```

This will generate a skeleton for a plugin.